# Etale $\pi_1$ of Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am forced to know the etale fundamental group of the grassmannian over the rational field. I searched it but couldn't find any hint. I am wondering whether there are some positive results or recipe to compute it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is that any Grassmannian is geometrically simply connected, so the etale fundamental group over $\mathbb{Q}$ is simply [**edit**: !!] the absolute Galois group $\operatorname{Aut}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.

In more detail: let $X$ be a geometrically integral variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, let 
$\overline{X}$ be its basechange to an algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{Q}} = \operatorname{Aut}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ be the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$.

1) Via a choice of geometric points (which we suppress), we get a short exact sequence of profinite groups

$1 \rightarrow \pi_1(\overline{X}) \rightarrow \pi_1(X) \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow 1$.

2) Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.  Suppose that *either* $X$ is complete or that $X$ is nonsingular [in our application, both hold].  Then the natural map
$\pi_1(\overline{X}) \rightarrow \pi_1(\overline{X} \otimes K)$ is an isomorphism.

[Comment: if instead of $\mathbb{Q}$, our ground field was a field $k$ of positive characteristic and $K$ is an algebraically closed field containing $\overline{k}$, this map is still an isomorphism for complete varieties but not necessarily for all smooth varieties and indeed, not even for the affine line!]

3) Take $K = \mathbb{C}$.  Then the analytification functor induces an isomorphism from the 
profinite completion of the topological fundamental group of $X(\mathbb{C})$ (with the $\mathbb{C}$-analytic topology) to the etale fundamental group $\pi_1(X \otimes \mathbb{C})$.

4) If $X/\mathbb{Q}$ is any Grassmannian, then it is nonsingular, complete and its analytification is the usual complex Grassmannian, which is simply connected: see e.g.

http://books.google.com/books?id=WHjO9K6xEm4C&pg=PA748&lpg=PA748&dq=simply+connected+Grassmannian&source=bl&ots=waYTv_whVx&sig=ErlPHYKL5FdQPUdBlIrIgYQGhbE&hl=en&ei=9FiITJuNNYjW9ASP_p3fDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q&f=false

Therefore putting the previous parts together the geometric fundamental group $\pi_1(\overline{X})$ is trivial, so we naturally have $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

References for these facts may be found, for instance, in Chapter 5 of Szamuely's *Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups*.

Comment: Pete, please state properness and geom. connectivity hypotheses. Anyway, when top. fund. group is trivial, can argue "directly": let $G$ be (proper & geom. conn'd) Grassmannian over $\mathbf{Q}$ and $E \rightarrow G$ a conn'd finite \'etale cover. Then  $E_ {\mathbf{C}} \rightarrow G_ {\mathbf{C}}$ is totally split since $G(\mathbf{C})$ is simply conn'd, so $E_ {\overline{Q}} \rightarrow G_ {\overline{Q}}$ is totally split (usual Nullstellensatz trick). Using Stein factorization for smooth proper *conn'd* $E$ over $\mathbf{Q}$, its "field of constants" $K$ has degree $[E:G]$, so $E = G_K$. QED

Comment: Hi. Thanks Peter and Brian for your helps! I appreciate. But in which step are the properness and geom. connectivity hypotheses needed? Sorry I am quite a beginner. 